# How can I get an iso image to boot from Ubuntu 16.04 grub 2 menu?

Tags: boot, grub2, iso, grubrescue

I'm trying to boot Macrium Reflect backup iso. Based on my current configurations, it tries to load, but it just reboots.

I have installed Memdisk and the iso file is located under etc\images. The iso boot up worked when I used Ubuntu 15.04 so I know that did not change.

These are the configurations setting for the menu option (I'm using the Grub Customizer):
Macrium Reflect Rescue Boot

```
set root=(hd0,1)
set isofile="/boot/images/Rescue.iso

loopback loop /boot/images/Rescue.iso

linux (hd0,1)/boot/memdisk iso raw

initrd (hd0,1)/boot/images/Rescue.iso
```

I've tried multiple things but nothing has worked his point, if someone can help me I sure would appreciated it.

Comment: If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions and information, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Answer (score -1):

Power on you PC while continuously pressing the appropriate function key for your model to bring up the BIOS menu. In Lenovo it is F2, in Hp it is F12.

Go to BOOT tab by using right arrow key

Select Macrium Reflect by using down arrow key

Press F6 as many times as needed so that Macrium Reflect moves to the top of other BOOT options.

Press F10. A pop up box appears. Yes is selected by default. Press Enter.

Your PC will reboot and will now boot into Macrium Reflect

Comment: Hi rancho

Thank you for you input, but the menu option is under Grub menu, not under the laptop bios option. When I boot up my Ubuntu laptop it will go to grub menu selection for 8 seconds. If I don't make a selection, it will boot to Ubuntu 16.04 normally. 

This is how I want it to work. I want to make an manually selection on the grub menu for Refect to run (currently it's option 2). It appears that the commands that I have listed are not correct. But it does not work when I select Refect boot option, it just restart the boot process.

Comment: Hi, according to the best of my knowledge there is no computer in the world where BIOS is not present or computer cannot be booted into BIOS or there is no boot order menu in BIOS. Next boot order is present in grub menu only for those OS s which are installed on the hard disk. Macrium rescue disk is a linux OS which boots up and is used to make an iso image of current hard drive to an external hard drive and vice versa. So not even the question of installing macrium rescue disk comes because it is not made that way.So basically what you are trying is technically not possible.

Comment: Also I wonder what was the exact process happening in ubuntu 15.04. Moreover I see no logic over why one would like to install macrium reflect linux OS and boot into it. It betrays the very concept of using this OS as a live media to boot up and create an iso image of the current hard drive into an external drive and restore the image when needed. So your question is also logically irrelevant.

Comment: @rancho https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: @rancho It is perfectly possible to boot into an ISO file from GRUB, and it makes sense to do so in some situations, particularly if your /boot partition is on a separate drive from your main system.

Comment: @Nick Weinberg OK I admit that in recent GRUB2 it is possible. I was wrong. But the statement that BOOT order is not present in BIOS is also wrong

Comment: @Nick Weinberg To boot linux ISO directly from grub menu is possible only when the live ISO is kept under any partition of currently installed linux system. Moreover you have to edit the /etc/grub.d/40_custom script. http://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/ Do Do it is not possible to boot a live CD from grub menu

Comment: Also one uses acronyum reflect rescue disk to make a copy of entire hard drive as an ISO. Making daily copy is not supported in linux. http://ask-leo.com/can_i_create_a_backup_image_of_linux_using_macrium_or_acronis.html Also it is not practical to backup linux by acronyum as the article clearly mentions. So the whole thing doesn't make any sense

Comment: Thank you Nick and rancho for your comments. rancho, this has nothing to do with with BIOS, Yes my system has BIOS but the loading of the Macrium Reflect starts after BIOS is complete. The iso is ran during the Grub operation.

Comment: You can make an image of Linux and restore it with no problem at all. I have used this method on 15.04. many times. Reflect is booted before Ubuntu is started so it can image all partitions and reapply them if nessacary. I use this method to recover after a bad upgrade or updates.

Comment: Nick I have the iso on Linux partition, I can't see 40_custom script, but I can see my configuration when I'm in Grub menu. Pressing "e" I can see each line that I have shown above.  By the way when it working I can backup to a Linux partition, I don't have to have an external storage to backup and restore images. Nick do you see anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Maybe the reason that the 40_customer script is not there is because I've installed and using Grub Configurator tool.